# Is the sound library WINMM.DLL found in every Windows Installation?

Tags: audio, winmm

I'm making a little open source mp3 player for people to see the code, etc. Proper comments, examples and what not.

I was wondering though, is the winmm.dll library found in every Windows installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for winmm.dll functions (like [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680%28VS.85%29.aspx)) says that they are available in Windows 2000 and later versions.

Comment: My Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit) has the winmm.dll :-)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I remember having used winmm.dll back in the days of win3.11

Comment: I think it was mmsystem.dll back on Windows 3.1.